# Android Reading a Text File

Tags: java, android, eclipse, text, filenotfoundexception

I am making a project in Android Studio, I have a text file in my project folder, each time I compile, I want my code to read that .txt file. When everythings finished, I want that .txt file to be inside .apk file. I am not trying to read from SD card etc.

But I am getting "File not found Exception" each time I compile. While using eclipse, when you place the .txt file in same directory as your project, code can find .txt file without problems but in Android Studio, it cannot find text file I just created. Where do I have to place my .txt file inside my project folder?
Here is the code:

```
FileReader in = new FileReader("TEXTgreetingKeywords.txt"); 
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

I used to same method to read text file in Java. I don't understand why it isn't working on Android since it uses Java too.

EDIT------

I used asset manager but I got the same error again

```
AssetManager asset = getAssets();
    try {
         in = asset.open("text.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Do I have to change the directory to something like "C:\App\main\text.txt" ?

Comment: Maybe the `assets` folder is the one you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

**Read Text** file From **Assets**:

**Create raw folder** in Resources directory:

**Paste** your file in **raw** folder:

**Read text** from **file**:

```
private String readText() {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(
                R.raw.license_agreement);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int i;
        try {
            i = inputStream.read();
            while (i != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                i = inputStream.read();
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To complete R. Adang comment : 
You're looking for the `assets` folder. You have to place it at the same place as the `res` folder. File in `assets` will be included in the APK.

You can access your files in `assets` by using [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html). Get your instance of AssetManager by using `context.getAssets()`

Comment: Thanks for the completion! :P Here, a up-vote for you

Comment: I tried as you said, I created an assets folder but when I try to access it by using code, I got the same error again. I am editing the question, can you check it again?

Comment: I tried the same thing with no problem. How did you create your assets folder ? Mine is here : MyApplication/app/src/main

Answer (score -1):

File access is not only java thing in this case, you have the android here as well and this can make problem. THe thing you're tring to by using `File` is opening file from application location. To get to you file directory you should use: `context.getFilesDir()`

than you use basic `File` constructor. I hope this is what you're looking for